# How do I do real-time streaming of video from a PIC32 with camera/Wifi module onto Amazon S3?

Tags: pic, wifi, video-transmitter

I'm looking at RTP/SIP stacks but don't know where to start. What are Live555, MPEG DASH, oRTP, and ffmpeg? Can they run on a PIC? I'm thinking 720p at 15 or 30 ips.

I have code working to upload videos onto an Amazon server, but I don't know how to do it real time, from a microprocessor.

I saw questions like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117210/where-to-start-building-this-wifi-video-streaming-circuit?rq=1) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49045/transmitting-a-video-stream-through-a-microcontrollers-wifi) but didn't see an adequate solution.

Comment: This is really a software question; the PIC will be able to handle RTP and SIP framing (have a look at pjsip if you want code), but not video compression. So that has to be done in the camera submodule.

Answer (score 2):

This question can only be answered once we know your resolution/framerate requirements. In general, I would consider the answer is a simple "No, it can't be done; the processing power is not enough".

You're probably better off with a system which has hardware interfaces for such tasks (e.g. CSI or MIPI) and can offload the required power to hardware.

Answer (score 1):

> What are Live555, MPEG DASH, oRTP, and ffmpeg?

- [Live555](http://www.live555.com/) is a company which provides a variety of media streaming applications, including the Live555 Media Server.
- [MPEG DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) is a protocol for transmitting MPEG video over HTTP. It's not a specific piece of software; I'll ignore it from here on.
- [oRTP](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/ortp/overview) is a library implementing the RTP streaming protocol.
- [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is a general-purpose audio/video transcoding application.

> Can they run on a PIC?

Almost certainly not. All of these libraries and tools are intended for use on systems running a full operating system, e.g, Linux. The system resources available on a PIC32 (e.g, 128 KB SRAM, 2 MB flash) are probably insufficient for the task, particularly considering that you would also need to implement a full network stack on the device!

Comment: Thank you!!! How do existing IP cameras, or Dropcam, do it then?

Comment: In the case of Dropcam, the device contains an [Ambarella A5s SoC](http://www.ambarella.com/products/security-ip-cameras) — a rather powerful processor designed *specifically* for IP cameras which includes a hardware video encoder — as well as 256 MB of DRAM and various other bits of support hardware.

Comment: How do you know all this?! You're so smart hahaha. I would upvote but I'm new and don't have enough reputation.
Okay, so if you were building a quadcopter to livestream to the cloud/a phone, but the quad had limited processing power, how would you go about it? What microprocessor(s) would you use and how would you deal with the RTP/SIP?